# Android heap size and SoftReferences

Tags: android

I have an application which creates a series of Bitmaps.  I am holding these Bitmaps in SoftReferences, to avoid running out of memory.  I would like the heap size to grow to the maximum 16MBs before it starts collecting my SoftReferences.  However, the SoftReferences are collected very eagerly, prior to growing the heap to it's max.  Is there anyway to force the references to be collected less eagerly? or to manually grow the heap to the max?  Possibly a way to just start the application with 16mb allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to modify the SoftReference collection behavior.

I'm not sure what you mean by "manually growing the heap to the max".

If these are instances of the Bitmap class (as opposed to some custom bitmap implementation), the pixel data is actually stored on the native heap, but uses an annoying "external allocation" accounting trick, which complicates the situation further.  (Notably, the storage is freed by a finalizer, not the GC, and finalizers have to execute in a separate thread after the GC completes.  It's possible to allocate Bitmaps until you run out of memory, and the GC has no way to release the memory before throwing an OOM error.)

Comment: by "grow heap to max" i was hoping for a way to force allocation of 16mb for my app, at startup.  something equivalent to: "-Xmx16m", from java.

Comment: That limits the maximum size of the heap, which is currently done (the Android app framework passes exactly that into the VM).  Were you thinking "-Xms16m", which would set the initial size?  That particular option won't do quite what you want because of the external allocation stuff.  There's a hidden method (was accidentally exposed initially, got hidden later) called dalvik.system.VMRuntime.setMinimumHeapSize that was meant to do roughly want you want, but it's just a hint and in any event is likely going to disappear in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue in Andriod. When VM collects soft references, it either collects all or none, although it should collect 'some' and should not collect anything when there is plenty of free heap.

Check: http://code-gotcha.blogspot.com/2011/09/softreference.html